# Какого рода слово ТОФФИ?

Tags: морфология

Какого рода слово "ТОФФИ"?

Answer (score 2):

С одной стороны, слово "тоффи" может иметь любой род, а также употребляться во мн.числе, так как обозначает различные кондитерские изделия (конфеты, соусы, пудинги, кремы, напитки), то есть род определяется   по видовому наименованию, например: "Давайте попробуем приготовить домашние тоффи!  Горячий соус «тоффи» – еще одно сладостное детское воспоминание». Совсем недавно  появилась новинка черного чая - шоколадное тоффи."Пирожные со сливочным тоффи и шоколадом".

С другой стороны, тоффи может восприниматься как несклоняемое сущ. ср. рода, обозначающее кондитерское изделие особого состава, например: "Неглазированная конфета, нежное сливочное тоффи".

Answer (score 0):

Женского, как "конфета" или "карамель": http://jeck.ru/tools/SynonymsDictionary/%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%84%D1%84%D0%B8.